# How to load popup using Ajax in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, popup

**Ajax popup window**

hi i am developing `php` web pages. 
I need to open customized popup window using ajax controls.
 How to use ajax for popup window?. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: checkout jquery ui dialog....;D

Comment: Why would you involve Ajax? You're opening a new window, not modifying an existing document, you can just set the URL for the window to load the complete document from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
jQuery 1.7.2.js
```

**Html**

```
<div id="yourPopup" style="padding:0; margin:0; display:none;">

</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function showyourPopup() {
    $("#yourPopup").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        resizable: false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        //show: { effect: "puff", duration: 300 }, 
        draggable: true
    });

    $(".ui-widget-header").css({"display":"none"}); 
}

function closeyourPopup() { $("#yourPopup").dialog('close'); }

/* Submit Resources Popup */

function submitResources(id){   

    $("#yourPopup").dialog('open');

    $.ajax({
        url:'your_page.php',
        data:'act=loadResourcesFrm&id='+id,
        type:'POST',
        error:function(){},
        success:function(data){ 
            $('#yourPopup').html(data); 
            showyourPopup();
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
if($_POST['act']=='loadResourcesFrm'){
echo "<table>
    <tr><td>
    Your Customized Popup window 
    </td></tr>
    </table>";

}
  ?>
```

Comment: `ajax({` without `jQuery/$`???? and what is `a,b,c,d`????

Comment: @Logesh - Just to add code is never helpful. You must explain your code properly with words also.

Answer (score 0):

For the alert popup box you can use

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('what you want to get on alert box!');</script>";
```

Other wise you can use `window.open()` for the hrml with `target="blank"`